# See or set Scene camera in Unity Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am quite new to developing with unity and the thing that bugs me the most is, that when I place assets in a scene that are a bit bigger and then delete them because I find them not fitting, I cant manage to find the 0 0 0 coordinate with my camera. I just placed a game object at 1600/-3600/-1200 because I don't know how I set the Editors camera to a specific point via mask or something. Also, I cannot see which position I am currently at. Do I have any possibility to do this while in editing mode?

Comment: Stupid way: Create an empty object, place it at 0,0,0 .. select it and press F ... For existing shortcuts see https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ShortcutsManager.html .. don't have Unity in front right now .. maybe there even is one for doing this directly

Comment: Or just left click on the cog at the top-right of the transform (the component context menu), and select "reset". (Also, double-clicking an object in hierarchy will focus/center it =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating a blank GameObject and set its Position to `0, 0 ,0`, select the GameObject in the Hierarchy, then hover your mouse over the Scene screen and press `F` to focus the editor camera on the GameObject.